# Не подгружается навигационное свойство

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
//Объект
public class Fcu : Entity<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int FcuTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual FcuType FcuType { get; set; }
}
//Навигационное свойтво
public class FcuType : Entity<int>
{
    //ctor
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Fcu> Fcus { get; set; }
}
```

**1. Контроллер**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(FcuCreateViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return PartialView("~/Views/Fcu/_Add.cshtml", model);

    var entity = new Fcu();
    entity.Name = model.Name;
    entity.FcuTypeId = model.SelectedFcuTypeId;

    // 1. Сохраняем
    _fcuService.Save(entity);
    // 2. Сохранили, теперь нужно его вытащить, нужен объект с уже 
    //   заполненным Id, т.к. Id не известен передаем Name
    var result = _fcuService.GetByName(model.Name);

    return Json(new { Fcu = result, Error = string.Empty });
}
```

**2. Сервис**

```
public Fcu GetByName(string name)
{
        var result = _fcuRepository.Get(x => x.Name == name);
        return result;
}
```

**3. Репозиторий**

```
public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
{
    return _dbSet.Where(where).FirstOrDefault<T>();
}
```

Навигационное свойство пустое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда в отладке раскрываю Results View: то навигационное свойство заполняется (как я понял идет дополнительный зарос к базе)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно сделать чтобы объект загружался с навигационными свойтвами? 
Использовать `Include`? То зачем мне тогда `LazyLoading`?

**Update**
LazyLoading у меня работает, вот для примера возьмем два теста (где `_sut` это `FcuService`):

```
// Тест - Проходит
// в этом тесте я ищу запись по имени
// и получаю заполненные поля + навиг. свойтво. все как должно быть.
[Test]
public void Should_Get_Fcu_By_Name()
{
    var result = _sut.GetByName("Fcu1");

    result.FcuType.Should().NotBeNull();
}

//Тест - Не проходит
//В этом тесте добавлю в бд новую запись и хочу ее загрузить, но мне 
//возвращается объект с пустым навигационным свойством, т.е контекст не 
//ищет объект в базе а просто отдает то что ему передал для сохранения
[Test]
public void Should_Insert_New_Fcu_And_Load_Back()
{
    var fcu = new Fcu { Name = "newFcu", FcuTypeId = 1 };

    _sut.Save(fcu);

    var result = _sut.GetByName("newFcu");

    result.FcuType.Should().NotBeNull();
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте сделать свойство `FcuTypeId` виртуальным.

Comment: Так Вам нужен LazyLoading (т.е. загрузка тогда, когда понадобились результаты) или EagerLoading (т.е. загрузка "сразу")?

Comment: @Zufir LazyLoading, но что-то не работает, я дополнил ответ

Comment: что бы на клиент передать сформированный объект вместе с заполненными навигационными свойствами необходимо сделать `Include()` or `Load()` иначе свойство будет заполнено в момент обращения

Comment: А если     `var fcu = new Fcu { Name = "newFcu", FcuType=_fcuTypeRepo.Get(x=>x.Id==1) };`?

Comment: @Bald попробовал через Include, не получилось, `var result = _fcuRepository.Get(x => x.Name == name, x => x.FcuType);` ![скрин](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20ty0.jpg).

Comment: @Zufir Ваш вариант работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При создании указывайте связанный объект, а не его Id:
`var fcu = new Fcu { Name = "newFcu", FcuType=_fcuTypeRepo.Get(x=>x.Id==1) }`